# ExpressJS preventing escaped apostrophes in interpolated variables

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am setting a variable to the current user being logged in but am receiving output back with escaped single quotation marks. Is there a way to prevent this escaping?

```
window.bootstrappedUserObject = <%= bootstrappedUser %>
```

Currently evaluates to

```
firstname: &#39;Rob&#39;,
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [features list](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/#features) for ejs. By default you can use `<%- bootstrappedUser %>` for unescaped buffering.